# Fake file upload in Chrome not showing file name

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, upload

I'm trying to use the solution over at quirksmode.org to sort the file upload input inconsistency problem, using the following javascript:

```
$('.sidebar-uploadcv input[type=file]').attr('onchange','javascript:document.getElementById("fakeupload").value = this.value').addClass('file_input_hidden');
```

The trouble is, this doesn't work properly in Chrome. It renders and the user can click to choose a file, but the filename isn't then displayed in the #fakeupload input.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow you to access the file directory with JS for security reasons. Any JS manipulation will create a C:\Fakepath\file.jpg if I remember correctly.

Comment: The thing is - even that isn't put into the fakeupload input field, which the above javascript should (I think) make happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by invoking `.change()` instead of `.attr('onchange',...)`. This method works cross-browser.

To get rid of the fakepath string in Webkit et al I've also added the `var filename...` line to strip out that part of the file name.

```
$('.input[type=file]').change( function() {
    var filename = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
    $('#fakeupload').val( filename );
});
```